# Does it matter for the sites which generated with static generator don't get X-Frame-Options,X-Frame-Options (XFO) header not implemented,

Tags: performance, security, cloudflare, hugo

using Hugo to generate a static site, but that didn't pass, "Content Security Policy”， and "X-Frame-Options ", and "X-XSS-Protection" with https://observatory.mozilla.org/. BUT get 100 with lighthouse.

when dealing with static site and host it with cloudflare page,  how should we approach security ?

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with Hugo. Cloudflare does not pass. The response header should be configured (correctly) on the server.

Source: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/x-frame-options